# How to get dynamic id from a class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating dynamic row with jquery. Now each row has different ID and common class name. How can I get the different id from same class name?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuCMv.jpg

See in the above picture. While I will select an option, then I want the ID name.

My Try:

HTML:

```
<tbody id="dynamic_row">
          <tr id="firstTR">

            <td>

              <select name="product_id[]" class="invoiceProducts">
                  @foreach($products as $product)
                    <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->productName }}</option>
                  @endforeach
              </select>

            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemDescription[]" id="itemDescription">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemCost[]" id="itemCost"></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="itemQuantity[]"></td>

            <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>

          </tr>

        </tbody>
```

```
$('#add').click(function(){  
   i++;
   j=i;

   console.log("Inside: " + i);

   var html = '<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added">';
   html += '<td><select name="product_id[]" class="invoiceProducts" id="itemSelect'+i+'">@foreach($products as $product)<option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->productName }}</option>@endforeach</select></td>';
   html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemDescription[]" id="itemDescription'+i+'"></td>';
   html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemCost[]" id="itemCost'+i+'"></td>';
   html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemQuantity[]" id="itemQuantity'+i+'"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>';

   let tb = $("table.invoice-table").find("tbody");
   tb.append(html);
   tb.find('tr').last().trigger('select-added');
});  


$('body').on('change', '.invoiceProducts', function() {
  var idOfSelect = $('.invoiceProducts').attr('id');
  console.log("Select ID: " + idOfSelect);
});
```

Output:

> Select ID: undefined

Comment: Simple answer: don't use dynamic `id` attributes. They're an anti-pattern which leads to needlessly complex logic which is more difficult to maintain. Use common classes and DOM traversal instead. If you edit the question to include the HTML and also what you're trying to do once you've got the `id` we can give you an example of how to achieve this.

Comment: Just my curiosity, why you need to set dynamic id instead use something like data-id?

Comment: Also, you appear to be asking how to get the `id` from an element you already have a reference to through the `this` keyword, as such the goal seems redundant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, please give me an example how can I do it simply.

Comment: As I said in the comment, if you want an example we'd need to see your HTML and an explanation of what you're trying to do with the `id`

Comment: use $this, $(this).attr('id')

Comment: I have added html code also.

Comment: jquery: `$(this).closest("tr").attr("id")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the id using `this.closest('tr').id` in the change event

```js
var i =0;
$('#add').click(function(){  
   i++;
   j=i;
   console.log("Inside: " + i);
   var html = '<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added">';
   html += '<td><select name="product_id[]" class="invoiceProducts" id="itemSelect'+i+'">@foreach($products as $product)<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>@endforeach</select></td>';
   html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemDescription[]" id="itemDescription'+i+'"></td>';
   html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemCost[]" id="itemCost'+i+'"></td>';
   html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemQuantity[]" id="itemQuantity'+i+'"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>';

   let tb = $("table.invoice-table").find("tbody");
   tb.append(html);
   tb.find('tr').last().trigger('select-added');
});  


$('body').on('change', '.invoiceProducts', function() {

  var idOfSelect = this.closest('tr').id
  console.log("Select ID: " + idOfSelect);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="invoice-table">
  <tbody id="dynamic_row">
    <tr id="firstTR">
      <td>
        <select name="product_id[]" class="invoiceProducts">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="1">2</option>
           <option value="1">3</option>
           <option value="1">4</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemDescription[]" id="itemDescription">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemCost[]" id="itemCost"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="itemQuantity[]"></td>
      <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help

```
$('body').on('change', '.invoiceProducts', function() {
  var idOfSelect = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log("Select ID: " + idOfSelect);
});
```

The trick is select ID of changed element, right?

Comment: The youtube link is unhelpful as it doesn't show the HTML so just shows "undefined" which you've already put in your comment.  The HTML in your question does NOT have an ID, but the `html+` DOES.  So this will likely work on any additional rows, but not the first. So you have multiple `select`s but your question doesn't ask about which one. Use jsfiddle or a snippet (if an answer) then we can quickly fix the fiddle to show you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `<select>` element, you should have `<option>` elements also as a children.

Just set "value" attribute of these children.

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option id="1" value="1"> A <option>
  <option id="2" value="2"> B <option>
  <option id="3" value="3"> C <option>
</select>

$("#mySelect").change(function(){
  var selectedOption = $(this). children("option:selected").val();
  console.log(selectedOption)
})
```

Comment: FYI You can use `$(this).val()` and it will give you the value= of the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with "document" It may help you Like:

```
$(document).on('change', '.invoiceProducts', function() {
  var idOfSelect = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log("Select ID: " + idOfSelect);
});
```